# My page doesn't change the web content when I use a switch statement

Tags: php, html

I have an error with my code where I'll select a link and then I will be redirected to the same `index.php` page but the variable on the end page = home with be different. This works in all my over projects but it does not work with this one.

Index.php

```
<?php include( 'pages/header.php'); ?>
<?php
    $page = isset($_GET[ 'page']);

    switch($page){
        case 'home':
            $title = "Home" ;
            include( 'pages/home.php');
            break;
        case 'about':
            $title = "About";
            include( 'pages/about.php');
            break;
        case 'features':
            $title = "features";
            include( 'pages/features.php');
            break;
        case 'pricing':
            $title = "Pricing";
            include( 'pages/pricing.php');
            break;
        case 'login':
            $title = "Login";
            include( 'pages/login.php');
            break;
        case 'register':
            $title = "Register";
            include( 'pages/register.php');
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Error';
            break;
    } 
?>
<?php include( 'pages/footer.php'); ?>
```

header.php

```
<nav id="mainmenu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="images/homr.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Home" /> <a href="index.php?page=home">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/about.png" width="30" height="30" alt="" />    <a href="index.php?page=about">About Us</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/features.png" width="30" height="30" alt="" /> <a href="index.php?page=features">Features</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/pricing.png" width="30" height="30" alt="" />  <a href="index.php?page=pricing">Pricing</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/register.png" width="30" height="30" alt="" /> <a href="index.php?page=register" target="_blank">Register</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/login.png" width="30" height="30" alt="" />    <a href="index.php?page=login" target="_blank">Log In</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="whitesmallmenu"><a class="button" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

What should happen is when I select the about link it should send the content about through the variable page and then the page variable will be used in a switch statement to see which page should be outputted.

What actually happens is that the page will have on the end of the url correctly but the home page show up instead of the about content.

Comment: You are assigning a boolean to the variable `$page = isset($_GET['page'])` and with that PHP will type juggle for the switch and match the first case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wrote:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']);
```

so `$page` will only be `true` or `false` and not contain the given content.

do something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    switch($page){
        case 'home':
            $title = "Home";
            include('pages/home.php');
            break;
        case 'about':
            $title = "About";
            include('pages/about.php');
            break;
       //...
} else {
    //... ie. include the startpage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use multiple `<?php` and `?>` tags in the same `php` file. You also `switch` boolean variable. Ok, jus change:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']);
```

To

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
            include('pages/header.php');
        ?>
        <?php
                $page = isset($_GET['page']);
                if($page === true){
                switch($_GET['page']){
                    case 'home':
                        $title = "Home";
                        include('pages/home.php');
                    break;
                    case 'about':
                        $title = "About";
                        include('pages/about.php');
                    break;
                    case 'features':
                        $title = "features";
                        include('pages/features.php');
                    break;
                    case 'pricing':
                        $title = "Pricing";
                        include('pages/pricing.php');
                    break;
                    case 'login':
                        $title = "Login";
                        include('pages/login.php');
                    break;
                    case 'register':
                        $title = "Register";
                        include('pages/register.php');
                    break;
                    default:
                    echo'Error';
                    break;
                }
             }
        ?>
        <?php
            include('pages/footer.php');
        ?>
```